# Reshape a 4D Tensor output of a Convolutional Layer to 5D Tensor to be fed to a ConvLSTM2D layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have a VGG Pretrained model. I pass images of shape (160,120,3) into it and batch size 10. Each frame in the batch represents a single time-step.

I know that the output is of shape (10,5,3,512) from the VGG network becasue I have passed batch size 10. But when I run `vggnet.output.shape` I obviously get `(None,5,3,512)`

Next I want to feed this output from the VGGnet into a ConvLSTM2D layer. But for this I hvae to convert it into a 5D tensor.

When I use `X = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((-1,10,5,3,512))(X)`, I get an error while training.
The error is

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Input to reshape is a tensor with 76800 values, but the requested shape has 768000
     [[node ds_model/reshape_2/Reshape (defined at <ipython-input-40-4fa9476bf8a0>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_5897]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

How to resolve this error? Is there any method to reshape the 4D tensor to 5D??

I want to convert `(None,5,3,512)` to `(None,10,5,3,512)`

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible using the API. Since the first co-ordinate is batch size, the other co-ordinates should match up. One possible way of achieving the same might be to slice up your tensor, and create a new tensor using that.

Comment: @pecey Is slicing a valid operation in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer

NUM_FRAMES = 16

class ReshapeLayer(Layer):
    def call(self,inputs):
        nshape = (BATCH_SIZE,NUM_FRAMES) + inputs.shape[1:]
        return tf.reshape(inputs,nshape)


inp = Input(shape = (H,W,C))
out = ReshapeLayer()(inp)
```

The above code works for reshaping the 4D input into 5D input provided, the 4D input contains has `BATCH_SIZE x NUM_FRAMES x H x W x C` elements.

`BATCH_SIZE` is for the LSTM part of the model